# What value in d makes this matrix diagonalisable over the field R?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, diagonalization

> Question: What value in $d$ makes the matrix
>
> $$
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>     0 & d & 0 \\
>     1 & 0 & d \\
>     d & 1 & 0 \\
>     \end{bmatrix}
> $$
> diagonalisable over the field $\mathbb{R}$?

My workings:

$=[(-1)(d)*(1- \lambda) (0- \lambda) - d^2]$

$=-d x( \lambda^2 - \lambda - d^2)$

$=(d)\lambda^2 + d(\lambda) +d^3$

After throwing it into $b^2-4ac$  :

$=d^2 - 4d^4$

The answer I got is $1/2$ as a root, but I am not sure if I am correct or if it's diagonalisable.

Edit : Apology for the terrible formatting, I am very new to stackexchange and I could not find a clue on how to type Lambda out. A clue on that as well would be awesome, thank you!

Comment: For lambda, you use \lambda (same for the other Greek letters): $\lambda$.

Comment: Just to be sure: it is in fact a $0$ in the top-right corner, and not a $1$?

Comment: Yes, it's 0. I just doubled checked what I posted in the question, it is correct.

Comment: You have to put \lambda inside $$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of your matrix is $-\lambda^3+2\lambda d+d^3$, whose [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_3) is $32d^3-27d^6$. So, the discriminant is $0$ if and only if $d=0$ or $d=\frac23\sqrt[3]4$. For every value of $d$ between those two numbers, your matrix will have $3$ distinct  real eigenvalues and therefore will be diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$ if $d>\frac23\sqrt[3]4$ or $d<0$, the discriminant will be negative, and therefore your matrix will not be diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$. Now, check by hand the cases in which $d=0$ and $d=\frac23\sqrt[3]4$.

Comment: Thank you very much, the link for discriminant was a nice touch!

Comment: If it's not too much, do you mind telling me how you got from 32d^3-27d^6 to d =0 and (2/3)*cuberoot(4)?

Comment: Right, got it. Thanks. 

(noticed you made a typo on the last reply, shouldn't it be a cubicroot?)